# How to make plot big enough to see every word in R?

Tags: r

[plot pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/THOop.png)

[image]
As the pic resolution is not high enough, I cannot read every word in my cluster dendogram.

How to fix this problem?

Comment: You can save it by `png("plot.png", width=20, height=20, units="in", res=500); plot(...); dev.off()`. plot.png should be saved in your current working directory.

Comment: Download patched version of R 3.0.1, bug has already been fixed stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/NEWS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [@DavidZ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44181822/how-to-make-plot-big-enough-to-see-every-word-in-r#comment75377724_44181822) said, we can change the resolution like below;

> You can save it by
>
> ```
> png("plot.png", width=20, height=20, units="in", res=500)
> plot(...) 
> dev.off()
> ```
>
> `plot.png` should be saved in your current working directory.